# How to save php excel file with today's date

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Past three days i am struggling with this excel file report generation. I can able to download the file. But i want to download the file with today's date. Like abcd_14/4/2014.xls. Below i given my code. Please help me to solve this issue.

excel_report.php

```
<?php

include("connection.php");
require_once("excel.class.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Download")
    {
    $payor_code = $_POST['payor_code'];
        $corp_code= $_POST['corp_code'];
        $pro_type = isset($_POST['product_type']);
        $submit_date = $_POST['sub_date'];


$dat = date("d/m/Y");

   $filename = "Report_$dat";

    $excel=new ExcelWriter("reports\STMB_report.xls");

$header = array(
    "ReceivedDate",
    "SubmissionDate",
    "PatientName",
    "PatientIC",
    "PrincipalName",
    "PrincipalIC",
    "ClaimNo"

       );
//$excel->writeLine($header);

    $excel->writeLine($header);
 $sql= oci_parse($conn, " select * from members ");

oci_execute($sql);
$dat = date("d/m/Y");


if($sql!=false)
{

        while($row=oci_fetch_array($sql))
    {

     $rec_date = $row['RECEIVED_DATE'];
    $sub_date = $row['SUBMISSION_DATE'];
    $pat_name = $row['PATIENT_NAME'];
    $nric_id = $row['NRIC_ID'];
    $pric_name = $row['PRINCIPAL_NAME'];
    $pric_nric = $row['PRINCIPAL_NRIC'];
    $claim_id = $row['CLAIMS_ID'];

        $header=array($rec_date,$sub_date,$pat_name, $nric_id, $pric_name, $pric_nric,$claim_id);
        $excel->writeLine($header);

    }
}echo "File Download succesfully";


}


?>
```

Excel Class file is,

excel.class.php

```
<?php

    $dat = date("d/m/Y");
//echo $dat;
   $filename = "Report_$dat";
 /*
     * Class is used for save the data into microsoft excel format.
     * It takes data into array or you can write data column vise.
     */


    Class ExcelWriter
    {

        var $fp=null;
        var $error;
        var $state="CLOSED";
        var $newRow=false;

        /*
        * @Params : $file  : file name of excel file to be created.
        * @Return : On Success Valid File Pointer to file
        *           On Failure return false  
        */

        function ExcelWriter($file="")
        {
            return $this->open($file);
        }

        /*
        * @Params : $file  : file name of excel file to be created.
        *           if you are using file name with directory i.e. test/myFile.xls
        *           then the directory must be existed on the system and have permissioned properly
        *           to write the file.
        * @Return : On Success Valid File Pointer to file
        *           On Failure return false  
        */
        function open($file)
        {
            if($this->state!="CLOSED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Another file is opend .Close it to save the file";
                return false;
            }   

            if(!empty($file))
            {
                $this->fp=@fopen($file,"w+");
            }
            else
            {
                $this->error="Usage : New ExcelWriter('fileName')";
                return false;
            }   
            if($this->fp==false)
            {
                $this->error="Error: Unable to open/create File.You may not have permmsion to write the file.";
                return false;
            }
            $this->state="OPENED";
            fwrite($this->fp,$this->GetHeader());
            return $this->fp;
        }

        function close()
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            if($this->newRow)
            {
                fwrite($this->fp,"</tr>");
                $this->newRow=false;
            }

            fwrite($this->fp,$this->GetFooter());
            fclose($this->fp);
            $this->state="CLOSED";
            return ;
        }
        /* @Params : Void
        *  @return : Void
        * This function write the header of Excel file.
        */

        function GetHeader()
        {
            $header = <<<EOH
                <html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
                xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

                <head>
                <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
                <meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
                 <o:DocumentProperties>
                  <o:LastAuthor>Sriram</o:LastAuthor>
                  <o:LastSaved>2005-01-02T07:46:23Z</o:LastSaved>
                  <o:Version>10.2625</o:Version>
                 </o:DocumentProperties>
                 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                  <o:DownloadComponents/>
                 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                </xml><![endif]-->
                <style>
                <!--table
                    {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
                    mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}
                @page
                    {margin:1.0in .75in 1.0in .75in;
                    mso-header-margin:.5in;
                    mso-footer-margin:.5in;}
                tr
                    {mso-height-source:auto;}
                col
                    {mso-width-source:auto;}
                br
                    {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
                .style0
                    {mso-number-format:General;
                    text-align:general;
                    vertical-align:bottom;
                    white-space:nowrap;
                    mso-rotate:0;
                    mso-background-source:auto;
                    mso-pattern:auto;
                    color:windowtext;
                    font-size:10.0pt;
                    font-weight:400;
                    font-style:normal;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    font-family:Arial;
                    mso-generic-font-family:auto;
                    mso-font-charset:0;
                    border:none;
                    mso-protection:locked visible;
                    mso-style-name:Normal;
                    mso-style-id:0;}
                td
                    {mso-style-parent:style0;
                    padding-top:1px;
                    padding-right:1px;
                    padding-left:1px;
                    mso-ignore:padding;
                    color:windowtext;
                    font-size:10.0pt;
                    font-weight:400;
                    font-style:normal;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    font-family:Arial;
                    mso-generic-font-family:auto;
                    mso-font-charset:0;
                    mso-number-format:General;
                    text-align:general;
                    //vertical-align:bottom;
                    border:none;
                    mso-background-source:auto;
                    mso-pattern:auto;
                    mso-protection:locked visible;
                    white-space:nowrap;
                    mso-rotate:0;}
                .xl24
                    {mso-style-parent:style0;
                    white-space:normal;}
                -->
                </style>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
                 <x:ExcelWorkbook>
                  <x:ExcelWorksheets>
                   <x:ExcelWorksheet>
                    <x:Name>STMB_reports</x:Name>
                    <x:WorksheetOptions>
                     <x:Selected/>
                     <x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents>
                     <x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects>
                     <x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios>
                    </x:WorksheetOptions>
                   </x:ExcelWorksheet>
                  </x:ExcelWorksheets>
                  <x:WindowHeight>10005</x:WindowHeight>
                  <x:WindowWidth>10005</x:WindowWidth>
                  <x:WindowTopX>120</x:WindowTopX>
                  <x:WindowTopY>135</x:WindowTopY>
                  <x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure>
                  <x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows>
                 </x:ExcelWorkbook>
                </xml><![endif]-->
                </head>

                <body link=blue vlink=purple>
                <table x:str border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style='border-collapse: collapse;table-layout:fixed;'>
EOH;
            return $header;
        }

        function GetFooter()
        {
            return "</table></body></html>";
        }

        /*
        * @Params : $line_arr: An valid array 
        * @Return : Void
        */

        function writeLine($line_arr)
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            if(!is_array($line_arr))
            {
                $this->error="Error : Argument is not valid. Supply an valid Array.";
                return false;
            }
            fwrite($this->fp,"<tr>");
            foreach($line_arr as $col)
                fwrite($this->fp,"<td class=xl24 width=64 >$col</td>");
            fwrite($this->fp,"</tr>");
        }

        /*
        * @Params : Void
        * @Return : Void
        */
        function writeRow()
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            if($this->newRow==false)
                fwrite($this->fp,"<tr>");
            else
                fwrite($this->fp,"</tr><tr>");
            $this->newRow=true; 
        }

        /*
        * @Params : $value : Coloumn Value
        * @Return : Void
        */
        function writeCol($value)
        {
            if($this->state!="OPENED")
            {
                $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
                return false;
            }   
            fwrite($this->fp,"<td class=xl24 width=64 >$value</td>");
        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Hopefully you have a folder tree that matches `14/04/2014` because `/` is normally used as a directory separator and is normally an illegal character in an actual filename.... `14-04-2014` (or `2014-04-14`) format would probably be a lot better to use

Comment: @hindmost : filename should be stored with today's date.  Example: $date =  date("d/m/Y"); $filename = abcd_$date.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

$dat = date("d/m/Y");

$filename="Report_(".$dat.").xls";

$excel=new ExcelWriter($filename);

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is:

You are not passing the $filename to the Excel class Open method, in order to save the file using you custom string i.e: Report_14/4/2014.xls

Do this:

> $filename = "Report_$dat.xls";
>   $excel=new ExcelWriter($filename);

Secondly: You cannot save files using names that contain invalid characters (like "/"), therefore change the split character where you are calling the php date() function.

> $dat = date('d-m-y');

Additionally with regards to writing content to the file:

You never set $conn before trying to connect to the database using $conn. If this is done in the connection.php file, you need to ensure the variable can be accessed in the scope of the code where you are calling it.

Then I would change the line reading

> if($sql!=false)

to

> oci_execute($sql);

and delete the previous call to oci_execute($sql);

to ensure you have data to loop through

Finally, you will not see any content in your file, if you do not close the file reader.

This is because many file handlers creates the file, but never writes to it on every "writeLine" call, because this will require many hardware IO calls which is expensive.

It therefore writes all those lines to a cache, and once you close the file handler, only then does it write the content to the file>

Thus, you need to call

> $excel->close();

where you echo

> echo "File Download succesfully";

to ensure the data is saved to file.

Comment: thank you.. I change the date format like date("d-m-Y") . The file name is changed. But inside the file i didnt see any data. I dont know what is happening. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I edited my post to explain why the file is empty. If you find my answer useful, please vote it up to indicate the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

> $filename = "Report_".$dat.".xls";
>
> $excel=new ExcelWriter($filename);

Comment: thank you ...  the below one is working,                                         $dat = date("d-m-Y");
$filename = "Report_".$dat.".xls";
$excel=new ExcelWriter($filename);                                  Now the file name is changed. But inside the file no date is there. Please help me to solve this issue. And also its over writing the data.

Comment: if your file storage path is something like report/report_14-04-2014.xls do check the write permission of that folder.Actually are you getting complete blank page or is it showing header value?

Comment: Now i got the proper result . Double quotes is missing .                $filename = "Report_".$dat.".xls";

$excel=new ExcelWriter("$filename");                                   One more help. I want to stored this file in one folder like, 

$excel=new ExcelWriter("reports\$filename");                          Note: If you open the file or the file name is already existing in the folder means it just rewrite the file content. I dont want like that. Every time i should download new file. ANY IDEA ?????

Comment: Append timestamp  with the file name then you can solve that.$filename = "Report_".$dat."_".time().".xls"